# Access App instance from MainWindow instance

Tags: .net, wpf

Is it possible to access `App` instance from `MainWindow` instance?

My `App` performs some initialization steps (like configuration initialization) and I need to pass the config to `MainWindow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`App.Current` should return this instance, you will need to cast it though.

Comment: Oh, thanks, cannot realize that I can cast it. Well, before I checked you (15 mins cap) - is it possible to access `MainWindow` from `App`? I bet it is not, but just to be sure ;-)

Comment: Yes you can, somewhat, but you need to make the MainWindow the actual main window of the application by using the [`Application.MainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx) property, otherwise you can try and find it in the [`Windows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx) collection of the application for example by checking the types of the windows.

Comment: the issue is - in `App.Init()` method `.MainWindow` hasn't been initialized yet...

Comment: Then you need to work with calls from the window to the app i suppose.

Comment: yup, that is why I asked about `Window -> App` direction in initial question ;-) Thanks for your help.